# Conditional Operator in ASP.net Databound Field (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement conditional formatting in a databound field in a DataList, but the error: `Invalid expression term 'if'` is being generated.
My code is as follows:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='
            <%# if (Eval("Description").ToString().Length <= 150)
            // The error is generated by the 'if' on the above line
                    Eval("Description");
                else
                    Eval("Description").ToString().PadRight(150).Substring(0,150).TrimEnd(); %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Note: The code in the `else` statement is largely irrelevant; I get the same error even when it's excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='
            <%# Eval("Description").ToString().Length <= 150?Eval("Description"):          
                    Eval("Description").ToString().PadRight(150).Substring(0,150).TrimEnd() %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, that did it. To make sure I understand how this works, I would like to ask if the following assumptions are correct:
**`?` is used to end the test statement.**
|
**`:` is used to start an `else` clause.**

Also, I would like to ask where I can find more information on the `DataBinder.Eval()` method. My searches so far have mostly only returned documenation on the basic use of the `Eval()` method.

Comment: conditional operator is : condition ? first_expression : second_expression; if the condition was true then first expression is evaluated else the second expression becomes the result, for more information check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'd not seen that before and it seems very useful.